# jQuery .each() function to modify DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

With the `jQuery.each` function I'm trying to get all of the ".jpg" related url's of a certain div. What I want to accomplish is to find each A element containing such url and insert the following HTML in it: `<li><img src="imgSrc"/></li>`

```
    $('#right a[href*=".jpg"]').each(function(index){  
        var imgSrc = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(imgSrc);
    });
```

this above example is all I've got right now, I've tried things like:

```
$('#destination img').attr('src', imgSrc);
```

To maybe make some things more clear the example below wil make things more clear.

```
<div id="left">     
   /* 
    Get the Urls of the a's in #right 
    and put them inside this div wrapped in an img tag: <img src="URL"/>
  */
</div>
<div id="right">
  <a href="http://example.com/images/example1.jpg"></a>
  <a href="http://example.com/images/example2.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: `'[bg-attr="paper"]` - where is that at in the html?

Comment: Yes I removed it to make things more clear, so the [bg-attr="paper"] has nothing to do with it anymore. Sorry

Comment: Are you trying to get everything at once and then display the final result?

Comment: what is `#destination`? do you mean `#left` ?

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood your question at first (and based on the upvotes for my blatantly-wrong answer, so did others :-) ). I've fixed it now.

Comment: Sorry #destination is indeed #left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally make a string then add that to a div somewhere. Here is an example.

```
var list = '<ul>';

$('#right a[href*=".jpg"]').each(function(index){  
    list += '<li><img src="' + this.href +'" /></li>'
});

list += '</ul>';

$('#destination').html(list);
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` - why not use `this.href`?

Comment: I overlooked that after copying and pasting. Edited answer because that's the right way to do it

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you mean you want to end up with:

```
<li><a href="http://example.com/images/example1.jpg"><img src="http://example.com/images/example1.jpg"></a></li>
```

...which isn't quite literally wrapping the links in that structure.

You can do that with [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), but it's an invalid structure — `div` can't have `li` as direct children. The only valid containers for `li` are `ul`, `ol`, and `template`.

You'd do it like this:

```
var $left = $("#left");
$('#right a[href*=".jpg"]').each(function() {
    $left.append('<li><img src="' + this.href + '"></li>');
});
```

You'll still have to deal with the `li` thing. :-)

Here's an example where `#left` is a `ul` rather than a `div`:

```js
var $left = $("#left");
$('#right a[href*=".jpg"]').each(function() {
    $left.append('<li><img src="' + this.href + '"></li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="left">
</ul>
<div id="right">

  <a href="http://example.com/images/example1.jpg"></a>
  <a href="http://example.com/images/example2.jpg"></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. You're right. in my example i used div's but actually it is an "Ul"

Answer (score 0):

Just add the url result with the html tag like:

```
    $('#right a[href*=".jpg"]').each(function(index){  

    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('href');
    var url = '<li><img src="' + imgSrc + '"/></li>';

    console.log(url);

});
```

Comment: This was the same thing I tried myself, but it didn't work for me. although thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `ul` element inside `#left` and I would add the image `li`s into this element as follows:

```
$(function() {
    var ul = $('<ul/>'),
        li = $('<li/>'),
        img = $('<img/>');
    $('#right a[href$=jpg]').each(function() {
        ul.append( li.clone().html( $(this).clone().html( img.clone().attr('src', this.href) ) ) );
    });
    $('#left').html( ul );
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var ul = $('<ul/>'),
      li = $('<li/>'),
      img = $('<img/>');
  $('#right a[href$=jpg]').each(function() {
    ul.append( li.clone().html( $(this).clone().html( img.clone().attr('src', this.href) ) ) );
  });
  $('#left').html( ul );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">     

   /* 
    Get the Urls of the a's in #right 
    and put them inside this div wrapped in an img tag: <img src="URL"/>
  */

</div>

<div id="right">

  <a href="http://example.com/images/example1.jpg"></a>
  <a href="http://example.com/images/example2.jpg"></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#right a[href*='.jpg']").each( function(){
        $("#left").append("<li><img src='" + this.href + "'></li>");       
    });    
});
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5jmr9qg/5/)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to use the $ selector to match all attributes ending with that string.

```
 $('#right a[href$=".jpg"]').each(function (index) {
   $('#left').append($('<li/>').append($('<img/>').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'))));
 });
```

Here is a fildde with a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lq1u2v7n/1/